# Select first half of text inside anchor tag using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to target the first half of the text inside an anchor tag using jQuery?

For example, I have these anchor tags.

```
<a href="">Go to Meeting Center</a> <!-- / target 'Go to' -->
<a href="">Our Departments</a> <!-- / target 'Our' -->
```

I'd also like to wrap them inside a span tag.

The result should be:

```
<a href=""><span>Go to</span> Meeting Center</a> <!-- / target 'Go to' -->
<a href=""><span>Our</span> Departments</a> <!-- / target 'Our' -->
```

It will be applied to all my anchor tags on my website.

Comment: show how should look the expected result

Comment: What does "first half" mean? Because your examples are not "half" by any measure I know of.

Comment: Yes, you can simply place a `<span>` element inside of the `<a>` element like this:

`<a href=""><span id="firsthalf">Go to</span> Meeting</a>`  then call `$("#firsthalf")`  to select it with jQuery

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I think OP is referring to the number of words instead of characters.

Comment: I just updated the question. By half, I mean the number of words inside the anchor tag divided by two. So if you have 4 words, it should target the first two words. If you have six words, it should target the first three words.

Comment: @LiberalTearsDrinker What about 5 words?

Comment: @uom-pgregorio, good question. I think it should just target the first or first and second words. The reason I want to target half of the text is so I could style them differently.

Comment: @LiberalTearsDrinker Ok check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
var text = $("a").text().split(" ");
var half_of_text = text.splice(0, Math.floor(text.length/2)).join(" ");
```

Comment: You will need to use this in a loop to go through all <a> tags as this on its own only does the first one.

Comment: I was assuming in the case that they were targeting just the one. It would be very easy to implement with as many as you want. The exact same concept for that matter

Answer (score 1):

The code below loops through all a tags, finds the half text you want (using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42519487/7053344)) and then creates the span with this half text and puts it in the `spans` div I created for the spans.

Check this [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/856w4zf0/1/).

**HTML**

```
<a href="">Go to Meeting Center</a> <!-- / target 'Go to' -->
<a href="">Our Departments</a> <!-- / target 'Our' -->
<div id="spans"></div>
```

**JavaScript/JQuery**

```
$('a').each(function(i, ele) {
    text = $(this).text().split(" ");
    half_of_text = text.splice(0, Math.floor(text.length/2)).join(" ");

    span = $(document.createElement('span'));
    span.html(half_of_text);
    $('#spans').append(span);
    $('#spans').append(document.createElement('br'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var t = $('a').text();
var middle= '';
for(var i =0; i<Math.floor(t.length/2);i++){
    middle+=t.char(i);
}
console.log(middle);
```

PS: This has not been tested and is done only to illustrate

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("a").each(function(){
  console.log($(this).text().substr( 0 ,$(this).text().length/2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="">Go to Meeting Center</a>
<a href="">Our Departments</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

"First half" is a very subjective term.

I fear you will have to code this by yourself,
a very basic approach :

```js
//assuming this is your query string
var text = "Go to Meeting Center";

//split string into an array
var terms = text.split(" ");

//looking for an approximate value the center of the text
var half = Math.ceil(terms.length/2);

//first "half" of query
var selected = terms.splice(0, half).join(" ");

console.log(selected);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide where is the middle by your own definition, but here is a way to detect the middle with the number of words. You'd get a span around a single word as well with this solution.

You first need to get the text inside the link and use the `split` function which creates an array from a string according to the separator passed in the argument.

Then, you create a span element containing those words you just replaced and you replace the text inside the link with that span.

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
[].forEach.call(links, function(link_el){
  var text_inside = link_el.innerText;
  var words = text_inside.split(' ');
  var words_half = Math.ceil(words.length/2);
  var span_element = document.createElement('span');
  var words_string = words.splice(0, words_half).join(' ');
  link_el.innerText = link_el.innerText.replace(words_string, '');
  span_element.innerText = words_string;
  link_el.prepend(span_element);
});
```

```html
<a href="">Go to Meeting Center</a> <!-- / target 'Go to' -->
<a href="">Our Departments</a> <!-- / target 'Our' -->
<a href="">Contact</a> <!-- / target 'Contact' -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following approach:

```js
$('a').each(function(i, el){
    var parts = $(el).text().split(' ');  // splitting anchor text into chunks
    $(el).html("<span>"+ parts.splice(0, Math.ceil(parts.length/2)).join(" ") +"</span> " + parts.join(" "));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="">Go to Meeting Center</a> <!-- / target 'Go to' -->
<a href="">Our Departments</a>
```

Used functions:
JQuery [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/)
[String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) (to split anchor text into chunks)
 
[Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) (to extract *the first half of the text*)
[Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Answer (score 0):

[Check this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aL24kqcu/2/)

#### HTML

```
<a href="">Go to Meeting Center</a> <!-- / target 'Go to' -->
<a href="">Our Departments</a> <!-- / target 'Our' -->
```

#### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.each($("a"), function(index, element) {
    var text = $(element).text().split(" ");
    text = text.splice(0, Math.floor(text.length/2)).join(" ");

    $(element).html($(element).text().replace(text, "<span>" + text + "</span>"))
  });
});
```

#### CSS

```
a {
  display: block;
}

span {
  color: red !important;
}
```

> **NOTE:**
>
> If you want to round down use `floor`, otherwise use `ceil`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some of the code provided in other answers to create an easy-to-use  approach for applying this to all links site-wide

(see snippet)

```js
function get_first_half(element) {
  var text = $(element).text().split(" ");
  var half_of_text = text.splice(0, Math.floor(text.length / 2)).join(" ");
  return half_of_text;
}

function get_back_half(element) {
  var text = $(element).text().split(" ");
  var half_of_text = text.slice(Math.floor(text.length / 2), Math.floor(text.length)).join(" ");
  return half_of_text;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").each(function(elem) {
    var first_half = get_first_half(this);
    var back_half = get_back_half(this);
    $(this).html("<span>" + first_half + "</span>" + back_half);
  });
});
```

```css
span {
  font-size: 2.0em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="">Goto Meeting</a>
<br>
<a href="">Our Departments</a>
```